# How do you deploy django applications for windows?

Tags: python, django, iis, deployment, isapi-wsgi

I'm working on a web application using [isapi_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/) and [django-pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/).  I'd like to have a way to install all dependencies and push the files out to the webserver.  Unfortunately, some of these are easier said than done.  In particular, handling dependencies is a pain as some of them won't install correctly even under setuptools (pywin32 is especially difficult).

Most of the tools that I see for automating this kind of stuff ([fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/) and [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/)) are made for use with unix-y systems.  I would like to set up a continuous integration system, but that only solves part of the problem.  Is there any way to make life easier for a Pythonista who's forced to use Windows/IIS?

Answer (score 6):

BitNami provides free [Windows Django all-in-one installers](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) that include all dependencies to deploy a Django app on Windows. Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of this tool. If you are going for a hosted version, we also have free Windows Amazon Machine Images (look further down in that page) but in that case I would strongly recommend going with a Linux-based AMI.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/index.html)? It might not be the perfect solution, but maybe better then your current process.

And it has setuptools (and other useful wrappers) built-in.

Comment: You're right, it's not a cure-all.  But it looks very interesting and helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays deploying your Django web project on a Windows based server has become less cumbersome. It's still challenging as most guides are geared towards Unix systems, but deploying on a Windows server is not impossible. Microsoft now provides some native support for Django with IIS.

However, you are not limited to IIS. You can use [Apache + mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). Here is one of my own test projects that you can deploy on Apache [my web project](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject).

- Guide: [Deploy Django with Apache and mod_wsgi on Windows Server 2019](https://youtu.be/frEjX1DNSpc)